# Downloading a plist as NSDictionary returns (null)

Tags: iphone, plist, nsdictionary

I have checked many questions on here about downloading a plist file from my server and converting it to a usable NSDictionary. For whatever reason, when I `NSLog` the `NSDictionary` created from the plist file, I get this in the console:

```
Timestamp: (null)
```

I know that it is a real file: http://www.faithlifefellowship.us/iOS/sermons.plist

Code:

```
NSDictionary* plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.faithlifefellowship.us/iOS/sermons.plist"]];

NSLog(@"%@",plist);
```

What is the problem?

Could it have anything to do with the fact that the plist file is minified?

**UPDATE:**

Getting the file with the following code:

```
NSString* pl = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.faithlifefellowship.us/iOS/sermons.plist"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",pl);
```

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>1</key><array><integer>1</integer><string>I've Been Redeemed</string><string>Ive Been Redeemed</string><array><string></string></array><array><string>03/20/09</string><string>04/02/09</string><string>04/10/09</string><string>04/24/09</string><string>05/13/09</string><string>05/23/09</string><string>06/06/09</string><string>06/13/09</string><string>06/20/09</string></array><string>http://faithlifefellowship.us/Sermons/Banners/Banner-IBR.png</string><integer>9</integer><array><string>Many Christians allow things in their lives, not realizing that they have been redeemed from them and because of ignorance of God's Word, do not walk in total freedom. This series will set you free in every area of your life!</string><string>It is important to be able to differentiate between a curse in our lives and suffering tribulation for the Lord's sake.</string><string>The same exact blessing that was on Abraham's life is now on our lives because of Jesus Christ. Don't let ignorance or unbelief keep you from all that God has for you!</string><string>Well, I guess God wants me to be sick to teach me a lesson, ever heard someone say that? Well that does not work EVER in the light of God's Word. Gal 3:13 Christ HAS redeemed us...</string><string>As we age the world says that we get weaker mentally, but God's Word does not agree with this. Part of what we have been redeemed from is an unsound and unstable mind.</string><string>Get up early, work late, still nothing ever seems to go your way why? Becasue of the curse. The Good News is that we have been redeemed from loss and failure in our lives!</string>
```

Blah blah blah and on and on...**it's all there**

Comment: Is the plist a valid plist? Also, you can try to get the file as NSData, convert it to string, NSLog it (to see the content) and than create a dictionary from NSData

Comment: That's the thing. I created a template plist in XCode and used it to make a new plist in PHP on my server, so I believe that it is valid...

Comment: Try to download it as NSData and convert into string to see the content, really, quite often it's just something annoyingly stupid like a problem with the url or similar, let me know if you get any data back ...

Comment: Please see the update in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are unescaped ampersands (i.e. '`Pt 1 & 2`') in this file, which is restricted. You should either replace them with `&amp;` on your server, or download contents of the file to NSString and then replace `&` with `&amp;`:

```
NSString *error;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.faithlifefellowship.us/iOS/sermons.plist"]
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                            error:&error];

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" & " withString:@" &amp; "];
NSData *plistData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData
                                                       mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                                                 format:&format 
                                                       errorDescription:&error];
```

Plus, there's a big problem with tags matching. You can validate your plist with http://www.xmlvalidation.com

Comment: Just wanted to point that out actually :) ... the plist is not valid, this answer is correct!